# jquery.js and jquery.keyframes.js are not found when using NPM

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-modules

I'm having trouble using jquery and jquery.keyframes. I use NPM and the js files are stored in the node_modules folder while the html files are stored in the public folder. For some reason the html file cannot find the js files when I use this code:

```
<script src="../node_modules/jquerykeyframes/dist/jquery.keyframes.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

I've tried a few alternatives but nothing has worked. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be importing your node_modules this way. You can either set a script up with node import/export (or require) or just  use the jquery cdn like so (https://code.jquery.com/):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And here is the link for jquery keyframes cdn: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquerykeyframes

Comment: Now I get "Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.load (jquery-3.6.0.js:10363)
    at jquery.keyframes.js:7
    at jquery.keyframes.js:184"

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could share your code. The thing is that you don't need jquery.keyframes.js. And you should execute your code on window load likt this: $(window).on('load', function(){ ...});

Comment: Adding: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script> made it work! thanks for all the help!

Comment: I had a look and found that you have all these npm packages that you aren't using. The thing is you have all these script tags in your html page but that has nothing to do with the npm packages you have installed. You have to import your package in your script file and can than use the npm packages.

Comment: Yes, the project is originally based on a template that contained all those npm packages so I'm going to sit down later and remove those who aren't needed.